# aspxgridview make a field required in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an aspxgridview list and it contains 3 Columns; Yes, No, Comment

When I press the "Edit" link of AspxGridview and Check "No", Comment field must be required othervise I do not have to make a comment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is my question clear? if not please warn me so that I can clarify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found an answer to this question.

[Link Devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T263022)

[Link Video](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/ad115792-2193-11e5-80bf-00155d62480c)